# Recursively traverse directory tree and print all files

Tags: beginner, file-system, f#

I want to build a small console program, that for given directory, will print (for now) all files inside that tree.

Here is an F# script that I came up with:

```
open System.IO

let getDirObjects (dir :DirectoryInfo) =
    let dirs = dir.GetDirectories()
    let files = dir.GetFiles()
    dirs,files

let rec traverse allFiles dir =
    let dirs,files = getDirObjects dir
    let allFiles' = Seq.append allFiles files
    let allFiles'' = dirs |> Seq.map (traverse allFiles') |> Seq.concat
    Seq.append allFiles' allFiles''

let printFileInfo (fileInfo:FileInfo) =
    printfn "%A" fileInfo.FullName

let printAllFilesFromDir path =
    let dirInfo = DirectoryInfo path
    let allFiles = traverse Seq.empty dirInfo
    allFiles |> Seq.iter printFileInfo
```

Changelog:

> #1 changed List to Seq to be more generic, no need to convert Arrays returned by GetDirectories and GetFiles to List

I've been reading about F# for past 2 weeks or so. This is actually first toy program that I wrote :)

One thing I don't like is `getDirObjects` function, that returns a tuple `DirectoryInfo * FileInfo`. Maybe this could be done in a more fancy way, with pattern matching or sth?

#### Update

*Here is much shorter version, whith same output.
It's get the job done, but my first intention was to do it in an F#, functional way. Please comment on the code above.*

```
open System.IO

let printAllFilesFromDir path =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(path,"*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")

printAllFilesFromDir "D:\_FTP"
```

Comment: why not just `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path,"*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)`?

Comment: okay, this is not so important. Why you want use `List` instead of `Array`?

Comment: Just a habit from C#, I think.
Even better, this could be done with `Directory.EnumerateFiles`

Comment: you mean List from `Collections.Generic`?

Comment: about `Directory.EnumerateFiles` you are right, just a typo :(

Comment: One thing though. Static method `Directory.EnumerateFiles` returns `IEnumerable<string>` which has only filename. I need full paths to file.
Method `EnumerateFiles` on `DirectoryInfo` object, returns `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`, which also contains `FullName` (full path)

Comment: really? `Directory.EnumerateFiles` returns the fullname, if I remember correctly

Comment: You are correct, I don't know why it printed only filenames when I first evaluated it. Current version is *MUCH* shorter now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42504/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-rakoczyn).

Answer (score 2):

```
let allFiles' = Seq.append allFiles files
let allFiles'' = dirs |> Seq.map (traverse allFiles') |> Seq.concat
```

Just because you can use `'` to differentiate variables does not mean that you should. Unless it's very clear what the different variables mean, you should use separate name for each of them.

---

```
dirs |> Seq.map (traverse allFiles') |> Seq.concat
```

You can simplify `Seq.map` followed by `Seq.concat` to just `Seq.collect`:

```
dirs |> Seq.collect (traverse allFiles')
```

---

```
let rec traverse allFiles dir =
    let dirs,files = getDirObjects dir
    let allFiles' = Seq.append allFiles files
    let allFiles'' = dirs |> Seq.map (traverse allFiles') |> Seq.concat
    Seq.append allFiles' allFiles''
```

This code is wrong. You pass files from the parent directory to each child directory and then return the parent directory files from each child directory and concat them.

For example, if you had two subdirectories, `dir1` and `dir2` and two files, `file-in-root` and `dir1/file-in-dir1`, then your code outputs:

```
file-in-root
file-in-root
file-in-root
dir2/file-in-dir2
```

Notice how `file-in-root` is output three times: once for the root directory, and also once for each subdirectory.

The solution here is not to pass `allFiles` to `traverse`:

```
let rec traverse dir =
    let dirs,files = getDirObjects dir
    let filesInDirs = dirs |> Seq.collect traverse
    Seq.append files filesInDirs
```

---

```
let dirs = dir.GetDirectories()
let files = dir.GetFiles()
```

Since you're using lazy `seq`s extensively, it would make sense to make `dirs` and `files` lazy `seq`s too, by using `seq`-returning `Enumerate*` methods instead of array-returning `Get*` methods. This way, if you enumerate the resulting `seq` only partially, it's going to be more efficient.

```
let dirs = dir.EnumerateDirectories()
let files = dir.EnumerateFiles()
```

Comment: Maybe `traverse` should be written as a sequence expression ; less "noise", no ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht You mean something like `seq { let dirs,files = getDirObjects dir in yield! files; for dir in dirs do yield! traverse dir }`? Yeah, that does look slightly better.

Comment: yeah something like that, accumalting a Seq using `Seq.append` felt unusual ^^ ; we can even get rid of `getDirObjects` : `seq { yield! dir.EnumerateFiles (); for dir in dir.EnumerateDirectories () do yield! traverse dir }` that way the code express directly the intent : yield each file in dir and then for each subdir traverse it